# Random Walk And Stochastic-Processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, exponential-function, random-walk

Assume that $P(X_i = 1) =1/2, P(X_i =-1)= 1/4,\text{ and }P(X_i = 0)=1/4$.
Consider the random walk starting at 1 given by 
$$S_n = 1 + X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$$  where  $X_1,X_2, ...$ are i.i.d.
What is the probability that the random walk ever reaches $0$?

I have tried to solve this using Binomial Theorem, but I do not have an equal probability here!
I would appreciate it so much if you could help me solve this problem.

Comment: Does 'ever reach zero' include $S_m=0$ $(m<n)$ but $S_n\ne0$? Or does it mean only $S_n=0$?

Comment: First, throw out $P(X_i=0)$ as they have no effect and rescale leftover probabilities to add up to one. Second, let $P_n$ be probability that the walk ever reaches $0$ starting at $n\ge 0$. Write down recursion for $P_n$ ($n\ge 1$) and solve it. $P_1$ is what you are looking for.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the re-scale part here. Could you explain this please?

Comment: $P(X=1|X\ne 0)=\frac{1/2}{1/2+1/4}=2/3$, $P(X=-1|X\ne 0)=\frac {1/4}{1/2+1/4}=1/3$.

Comment: We are only interested in which direction it goes, not how long it stays there.  It goes up twice as often as it goes down, so the probabilities are 2/3 and 1/3.

Comment: Actually, you don't need any of the rescaling/throwing out $X=0$ that I mentioned - though it makes it easier to thing of what the walk actually does. Just write down recursion for $P_n$ for the original walk and solve it (it will be equivalent to the recursion for the modified walk).

Comment: Thanks Michael and A.S., It makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it reaches $0$ in n steps. We can calculate the probability using the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution). Out of n steps some k will be +1, k+1 will be -1, and n-2k-1 will be $0$.

Hence, $P(S_n=0) = \sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2} (1/2)^k (1/4)^{n-k}\frac{n!}{k! (k+1)! (n-2k-1)!}$

Comment: Great ! 
I appreciate your help. Thanks a million

Comment: @JoyGardenia dont thank. If you like the answer just upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Let P1 be the probability it ever reaches 0, starting at 1, and P2 the probability it ever reaches 0, starting at 2.
To reach 0 from 2, it has to reach 1 from 2, then 0 from 1.
Reaching 1 from 2 is the same as reaching 0 from 1.
So the probability $P2=P1^2$
Now, start at 1, and make one move.  The chances are 1/3 you are at 0 (success!) and 2/3 you are at 2.  So $$P1=\frac13(1)+\frac23(P2)\\1-3P1+2P1^2=0\\(1-2P1)(1-P1)=0$$
So P1=1 or 1/2. :(

Answer (score 0):

The probability of *ever* reaching zero does not depend on the probability to not move at all. Thus you can instead consider the walk with a $2/3$ chance to go right and a $1/3$ chance to go left. There is a nice general solution to this problem. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then the probability to hit $0$ before hitting $n$ starting at $0<x<n$ satisfies:

$$u_n(x)=\frac{2}{3} u_n(x+1)+\frac{1}{3} u_n(x-1).$$

Adjoin this to the boundary conditions $u_n(0)=1,u_n(n)=0$. Then the recurrence relation can be solved explicitly. (Hint: the general solution is of the form $c_1 r_1^x + c_2 r_2^x$, where $r_1,r_2$ are the roots of $\frac{2}{3} r^2-r+\frac{1}{3}$.) Then the desired quantity is $u(1)=\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n(1)$.

Comment: @A.S. You might misunderstand: in reality, we are solving for infinitely many functions $u_n(x)$, defined for $0 \leq x \leq n$. Then we considering $u(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n(x)$. Are you asking for justification that $\lim_{x \to \infty} u(x)=0$?

Comment: @A.S. It will automatically be a solution of the corresponding recurrence equation with no boundary on the right. It is the correct one for probabilistic reasons (perhaps they are not obvious?)

Comment: @A.S. I am considering the sequence of problems "what is the probability of hitting $0$ before hitting $n$", and then sending $n$ to infinity. This is correct because if you consider the complementary event (never hitting $n$), you will have to hit arbitrarily large values along the way to achieve that event.

Comment: How do I calculate the probability that the random walk reaches, for example, 3 before reaches 0 if we start at 1 ? Do I still consider the random walk with 2/3 chance to go right and 1/3 probability to go left, and why?

Comment: @JoyGardenia That would be $u_3(1)$, in the notation above. And yes, you would still consider the walk where you disregard the steps where you stay where you are. That's because the steps where you don't move don't affect what you hit, they only affect when you hit it. But if you prefer, you can include that term as well, it will just cancel out algebraically when you write out the total probability formula and solve for $u_n(x)$.